# MongoDB How to update the first item that matches a condition in an array of documents?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a sample document:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    exams: [
               {name: 'a', score: 2},
               {name: 'b', score: 9},
               {name: 'c', score: 7}
           ]
}
```

I need to set the `score` of the first element that has a `score` higher than 7 in the `exams` array to 10, for a document specified by `_id`.

So in the case of the sample document, I need to update it to:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    exams: [
               {name: 'a', score: 2},
               {name: 'b', score: 10},
               {name: 'c', score: 7}
           ]
}
```

What would the Mongo shell query be for this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $gt to find higher score

```
updateOne({"exams.score":{ $gt: 7 }},{$set:{"exams.$.score":"10"})
```